# Negative eigenvalues of Sturm-Liouville Boundary -Value Problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying Sturm-Liouville Boundary-Value Problem chapter in differential equation. I solved many problems to find eigenvalues and eigenfunction of the problems. But i did't find any example with negative eigenvalues. Is the any result regarding negative eigenvalues? like it may not have negative eigenvalues?
Please give me some example or any result regarding this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Under some conditions, yes. See the first theorem here: http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse35.html

Comment: ok ...thanks...